# ZF2 nested views as array

Tags: arrays, view, zend-framework2

is it possible to add multiple views in a array to a parent view in Zend Framework 2?
For example:

childView.php

```
echo $this->data;
```

parentView.php:

```
foreach($this->views as $view)
    echo '<div>'.$view.'</div>';
```

controller.php:

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $children = array(1,2,3);
    foreach($children as $child){
        $childView = new ViewModel(array('data' => $child));
        $childView->setTemplate('childView');
        $childrenViews[] = $childView;
    }
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('parentView');

    // some function that adds the childrenViews to the parentView;

    return $view;
}
```

Expected output: `<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>`

ps: It's dummy code so please ignore possible syntax errors.

Comment: Maybe take a look at Akrabats `Zf2TestApp` -> http://zf2test.akrabat.com/, particularly the multiple view models -> http://zf2test.akrabat.com/view/multipleViewModels. You can find the source on github (it's linked from the test app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $children = array(1,2,3);
    foreach($children as $child){
        $childView = new ViewModel(array('data' => $child));
        $childView->setTemplate('childView');
        $view->addChild($childView, 'the-child-views', true);
    }
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTemplate('parentView');

    return $view;
}
```

This line:

```
$view->addChild($childView, 'the-child-views', true);
```

Will append the child views to this one var. So you can echo your views using:

```
<?php echo $this->the-child-views ?>
```

Hope it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can just assign the array of ViewModels to your parent View Model.

```
<?php
public function actionIndex()
{
    $children = array(1,2,3);
    foreach($children as $child){
        $childView = new ViewModel(array('data' => $child));
        $childView->setTemplate('childView');
        $childrenViews[] = $childView;
    }
    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setVariable('children', $children); // assign to $children
    /**
     * Or set in constructor
     */
    //$view = new ViewModel(array(
    //    'children' => $children
    //));

    $view->setTemplate('parentView');

    return $view;
}
```

Now you can just iterate over them in your parent template:

parentView.phtml

```
<?php // $children or $this->children to access your array of ViewModels ?>
<?php foreach($children as $child): ?>
    <?php echo $child // automatically rendered for you ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me because addChild expects an interface as the first parameter. And an array does not statisfy that.

Comment: Your answer seems better than the accepted because of your example, which is easier to understand and gives the right context

Answer (score -1):

I think it should work with the partial helper:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#partial-helper